# Java StringBuffer: replace the content from a starting index to the end of a line

Tags: java, replace, stringbuffer

I have content of a file in a StringBuffer. The content of the file includes many lines (not on a single line). I want to edit the content of a line from index 4 (just for example) to the end of that line. I use `replace()` to edit the content of the StringBuffer.

The point is that the replace method has parameters such as starting index and ending index. But I don't know what is the ending index since each line have different number of characters

I think of using `str.indexOf("\n")` to find the ending index of the line, but then the file have many lines, so it will return incorrect results.

this is the `readFile()` if u need to read the code

Thank you

```
public StringBuffer readFile(){ //read file line by line
    File f = getFilePath(fileName);
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    String textinLine;

    try {
        FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(f);
        InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(fs);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(in);

     while (true){
            textinLine = br.readLine();
            if (textinLine == null) break;
            sb.append(textinLine+ "\n");
        }
        fs.close();
        in.close();
        br.close();
    } ... // just some catch statements heres
}
```

Comment: Why don't you apply your change to each line separately as you read it in, before appending to the StringBuffer? (BTW, use StringBuilder instead, it's faster)

Comment: b/c I'll need to read the file again so I write a method that read file and return StringBuffer instead...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `String.indexOf()` as you indicated, but pass in the starting position, e.g. `indexOf('\n', 4);`

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Jim's idea, why not process string before appending it to StringBuffer.

By the way, I think you can use `indexOf(String str, int fromIndex)` function to parse StringBuffer, and each time when you get `'\n'`, you can set an offset value, then next time when you get the next `\n`, you can just let index value plus the offset.